# Array element becomes undefined after asynchronous function call in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

**Problem Description:**
I'm encountering an issue where a specific element of my file array becomes undefined after using an asynchronous function to check the size of image files. Although all asynchronous processes complete successfully, attempting to access the array element results in undefined.
console.log(`2${copyFile[i]}`); return "2undefined"

**Relevant Code:**

```
 this.addFiles = async function (files)
    {
        let falseFiles = [];
        const copyFile = files;
        var dataGrid = self.dataGrid;
        for (let i = 0; i < copyFile.length; i++) {
            console.log(`1${copyFile[i]}`);
            const checkImageLimitFlag = await this.checkImageLimit(copyFile[i]);
            console.log(`2${copyFile[i]}`);
        }
    }
```

```
this.checkImageLimit = async function (file){
       let isValid = true;
        try {
            const maxWidth =1000;
            const maxHeight =1000;
            const { width, height } = await this.loadImage(file);
            // if(validExtension.includes(extension)){ 
                if(width > maxWidth || height > maxHeight)
                    isValid = false;
            // }
        } catch (error) {
        }
        return isValid
}
```

```
this.loadImage = function(file) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const reader = new FileReader();
      
          reader.onload = function (e) {
            const img = new Image();
      
            img.onload = function () {
              resolve({ width: img.width, height: img.height });
            };
      
            img.onerror = reject;
            img.src = e.target.result;
          };
      
          reader.onerror = reject;
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        });
      }
```

**Attempted Solutions:**

I've reviewed the code to ensure the array is not modified within the asynchronous function.
Used console.log to check the state of the array before and after the asynchronous calls.
Tested to see if the same problem occurs in different browsers and environments.

**Questions:**

Why does an array element become undefined after a call to an asynchronous function using the await keyword?
Are there any possible approaches to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you saying that `1${copeFile[i]}` shows a value but `2${copyFile[i]}` shows undefined? I'd be looking outside your call to `addFiles()` to see if anything changes the array / FileList you're passing in. Please [edit] your question to contain a [mre]. Whatever the cause of the problem is, it is not in the code you've shown so far

Comment: you probably think that this `const copyFile = files;` copies your array. it does not. it copies the pointer to the array. to copy the array do `const copyFile = [...files];`

Comment: When I set a breakpoint at 1${copyFile[i]}, the file object appears normal. However, after running the checkImageLimit function, by the time it reaches 2${copyFile[i]}, the copyFile object becomes inaccessible. I have updated the source code accordingly

Comment: I understand that files contains file objects and are immutable, so I thought that deep copying would not be possible without using FileReader, and hence, I did not proceed in that way

Comment: Cannot reproduce https://plnkr.co/edit/FBcSDkxRN23zMt1Z?open=lib%2Fscript.js. Note, a `FileList` is not an `Array`.

Comment: I second @guest271314 assertion that the code as shown in the question works fine - the issue must be in the actual code

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the code that calls `addFiles()`. Show where the `files` parameter comes from and **anything** that happens to it after you've called `addFiles()`